# How do I open up and run a Django server on a Microsoft OS?

Tags: django, cmd

I am fairly new to the world of coding and am looking to learn. I have been taking some online classes on Lynda.com and learned how to fire up a Django server but once I fire it up and come back later to work on it I am having trouble firing the server back up.  Can you help?  I am working with CMD in a Microsoft 10 OS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the python interpreter, you should be able to run `python manage.py runserver`. I would strongly recommend looking at [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/)

Comment: Perfect I got it. Why do you like PyCharm?

Comment: Does .py just mean a python file?

Comment: Yep, `.py` is just the python file. It will automatically create your virtualenv environment and execute files (scripts).